# Great tab order on SE, except for one thing

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, behavior

On the Internet I usually don't use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go anywhere, but today was the day. Way to go dev-team.

One thing:

- Inside a question, the 'flag' link is skipped. It should be after 'edit'.

Very nice feature!

Comment: I am able to repro that. weird (im on Chrome 12)

Comment: I'm on Firefox 3.6.18

Comment: It looks to me like the focus is set on the search box. At least, if I press Tab, that's the first place I land. That seems cool to me, too. At least as good as, if not better than, the first question.

Comment: @Cody, you're right. I must have gotten some odd result after [F5] or something. Edit out. After the searchbox, though, it runs through the whole header section. I guess there's nothing to be done about that.

Comment: Repro on Firefox 5 in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, it was happening because these links had no `href` attribute.  They are now `href="#"` with a `e.preventDefault()` in the JavaScript to stop navigation to the hash.