# We jump for joy when we flag, but we don't expect the page to

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Nick [implemented a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99160/great-tab-order-on-se-except-for-one-thing/102956#102956) yesterday that gave a `href` attribute to some of the links in `.post-menu`, which seems to work great. Unfortunately, with the exception of Meta it looks like the change was only half-deployed to the network, since the screen will jump up to the top due to the link's hash being added to the URL on other sites.

Checking the source suggests that his HTML change was pulled, but not the JavaScript update which added `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: This is definitely in the running for best title of the month.

Comment: This is annoying. Especially when flagging an answer - whole page scrolls up to the top before you get the flagging popup, so you're not really sure that you will indeed be flagging the answer and not the question.

Comment: This is awkward, I really double checked the popup element with the Debugger to see if I flagged the right post.

Comment: This is the first question I see whose first four consecutive comments (including this one) all start with "This is".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a cache issue with our CDN provider, indeed they did not pull the updated JavaScript.

I manually ran a purge on this, simply refreshing the page should fix the issue for now (the next build with a JS change will also force a local purge via the querystring).

Comment: Isn't that very scary? Or did the `<script src="...?v=35345ae3f304">` not include any query string for some time? (SE has included query strings in references to the static resources since long, so unless the HTML source did not include that for some time, I'd be very scared if the CDN just decided to return *some* similar resource.)

Comment: @Arjan - it did include the querystring...that's really just a trigger to tell the browser "hey buddy, grab it again", and while that *did* happen, it was *still* getting an old version from the CDN, since that's what the CDN nodes had cached.  The fact the CDN didn't *actually* purge the cache and didn't tell us there was anything wrong, yes that's troubling.  We're looking at some changes to make the CDN better for all involved coming up though, stay tuned.

Comment: As an aside, I guess you know that a caching *proxy* should never mix resources that have a different query string. Not knowing a lot about CDNs, I'd expect the same to be true for a CDN. But maybe for CDNs there are different agreements between the CDN and the website owner? (I could imagine that neither the website owner not the CDN would be happy if a visitor —rather than the website owner— added random query strings to "static" content. And to "handle" such abuse maybe a CDN has documented that it will return known content then?)

Comment: @Arjan - It's really a side-issue, while yes that's true, it doesn't matter in our case. There is in fact only one file (as far as the CDN goes, the querystring doesn't matter, and we only cache one copy there), also we purge the CDN when we build (an API call as part of the build process).  The only thing that needs to happen is the browser gets a new querystring to re-fetch *after* a CDN purge has occurred...and while that happens in the correct order by nature of how we deploy, the CDN's lack of a purge shafted us here.

Comment: And *totally* as an aside: sometimes it would be nice if old versions of the resources would be available. I understand how things work now, and I know it's hard to maintain old versions too. But, for example, [for bug reports](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62712#c6), it would be nice if there's some Time Machine ;-). (Having said that, I've never bothered to supply that myself either...)